# using for loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        $("#"+i).hover(function() {
             $("#"+i).stop().animate({left:"50px"});
        },
        function() {
             $("#"+i).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
        });
    } 
 });
```

I used for loop here to avoid multiple declaration of hover 
function it doesnt work how can i declare my div id my div id was 1-7.plz tell me how 
i should use the div ids inside the loop.

Comment: Please [format your question and code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so that other people can read it.

Comment: This can be done with CSS. No need for jQuery...

Comment: 1) Do u use numeric ID? 2) for tag has $ - should be an error.

Comment: The `for` keyword doesn't have a `$`.

Comment: Please do not format coding mistakes out of your question as errors are pointed out - it makes the answers look wrong

Comment: im sorry this is my 1st posted question,im not femiliar to this

Comment: @user1100418 - no problem.  In the future you can highlight the code in your question and click the {} button to format it nicely.  This will help people trying to answer you question.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are using numbers as ids, here is a great answer on StackOverflow that describes how to create IDs: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    for(var i = 1; i < 8; i++)//see that I removed the $ preceeding the `for` keyword, it should not have been there
    {
        $("#"+i).hover(function() {
             $(this).stop().animate({left:"50px"});//also notice that instead of using `"#" + i` as the selector inside the anonymous function I changed it to `this` so it properly references the hovered element
        },
        function() {
             $(this).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
        });
    } 
});
```

If you add a class to all of the elements you are binding to this can be majorly simplified:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".hover-class").hover(function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({left:"50px"});
    },
    function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
    });
});
```

Here is a demo of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/FJQNa/

This will select all the elements with the `hover-class` class and bind the `mouseover`/`mouseout` event handlers to them.

**EDIT**

You can also select multiple elements at once using ids by separating selectors with commas:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#ele-1, #ele-2, #ele-3, #ele-4, #ele-5, #ele-6, #ele-7").hover(function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({left:"50px"});
    },
    function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
    });
});
```

Docs for multiple selectors in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: thank you can u tell me how can i declare it . to avoid its multiple declaration

Comment: @user1100418 I'm not sure I understand your question. If you are talking about the second code example in my answer, then check-out the jsfiddle (the link below the code) and you can see how the HTML/CSS/JS are implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Use `this` instead of `i`.  `i` lasts beyond the for loop so it will always try to access $('#8')`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    for(var i=1; i<8; i++) //Declare var here otherwise it becomes global and that's not what you want for a simple counter
    {
        $("#"+i).hover(function() { //i is valid here because it gets used synchronously with the loop
             $(this).stop().animate({left:"50px"});
             //Use this instead of i because of "closure."
             //The anonymous function gain access to the variable to be
             // used later, but the loop will continue to increment,
             // changing the value.
        },
        function() {
             $(this).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: thank you can u tell me how can i declare it . to avoid its multiple declaration

Answer (score 4):

This is how you make a for loop in JavaScript:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 8; i++)
```

No jQuery needed.

Also, you're using numbers as ids for your dom elements, which is invalid.  IDs are supposed to start with a letter.

Also, those inner functions are using your loop's variable, which is not going to work; you'll wind up with each handler trying to select element 8 since each handler is closing over `i`.

To pass the current value of a changing loop variable to an underlying event handler, you'd have to "break the closure" like this:

```
$("#el"+i).hover(
    (function(local_i) { return function() {  $("#el"+ local_i).stop().animate({left:"50px"});  } })(i),
    (function(local_i) { return function() { $("#el" + local_i).stop().animate({left:"30px"}); } })(i) 
});
```

But you're really just grabbing the thing you're hovering over, so:

```
    $("#"+i).hover(function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({left:"50px"});
    },
    function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
    });
```

Should work fine

Comment: Plus the fact that scoping is an issue here. But that might go a bit too far if the OP does not know how to make a for loop...

Comment: Another note: The animation will always run on element with "id" 7, because of i changes at every iteration, and `i` is not captured in a closure.

Comment: @pimvdb - oh my - he's using the loop value in events - that won't work at all

Comment: The immediately-invoked anonymous function is definitely overkill here.  Also, numeric ids are valid HTML5.

Comment: @Dennis - I didn't know numeric id's were valid for html5.  Will they break older browsers?

Comment: @AdamRackis http://jsfiddle.net/QHevQ/ They work fine in IE7, I've never had problems with numeric ids (not that I use them that often).

Comment: @Dennis - it's always interesting to see what invalid things older browsers will tolerate.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1100418 - great, glad to hear it.  And welcome to Stack Overflow.  Make sure you mark whichever of these answers was most helpful by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Classes would be the better solution (another already posed this solution) If you absolutely must use IDs this might work out a little better:

```
var selector = "#1";
for(var i = 2; i < 8; i++)
   selector+=",#"+i;

$(selector).hover(
function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({left:"50px"});
},
function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({left:"30px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using classes can not only group them semantically, but also makes selecting them easier. Use `this`. You can also use jQuery.each() to add behavior to all the selected elements.

```
$(function () {
    function move50 () {
        $(this).stop().animate({left: "50px"}, 500);
    }
    function move30 () {
         $(this).stop().animate({left: "30px"}, 500);
    }
    $(".mydiv").each(function (i, elem) {
        $(elem).hover(move50, move30);
    });
});
```

Try it here - http://jsfiddle.net/dkBY2/